# Perl's printf width modifier not working in map operator

Tags: perl, printf

Why is it that when I do `map{printf "%4s\n",File::Spec->rel2abs($_)}glob '*';` OR `print map{sprintf "%4s\n",File::Spec->rel2abs($_)}glob '*';` the 4 space characters are output to the left of the strings?...

```
/var/www/html/Physics/Electronics/file1.txt
/var/www/html/Physics/Electronics/file2.txt
/var/www/html/Physics/Electronics/file3.txt
/var/www/html/Physics/Electronics/file4.txt
```

It seems that I have to do `map{print "\x{20}\x{20}\x{20}\x{20}",File::Spec->rel2abs($_),"\n"}glob '*';` in order to output the 4 space characters to the left of the strings...

```
    /var/www/html/Physics/Electronics/file1.txt
    /var/www/html/Physics/Electronics/file2.txt
    /var/www/html/Physics/Electronics/file3.txt
    /var/www/html/Physics/Electronics/file4.txt
```

Comment: `map` in void context is just an inefficient `foreach` loop. `glob` already sorts its results.

Comment: Why do you think `%-4s` should add four spaces?

Comment: @Borodin I was misunderstanding its meaning.  I incorrectly thought it prepends 4 characters, but it's a minimum width field modifier as melpomene answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%4s` (or `%-4s`) does not mean "add 4 spaces to this string". It means "output this string with a minimum field width of 4", i.e. strings shorter than 4 characters will be padded with spaces. See also [`perldoc -f sprintf`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/sprintf#(minimum)-width).

If you want to always add 4 spaces at the beginning, just do

```
for my $file (glob '*') {
    print "    ", File::Spec->rel2abs($file), "\n";
}
```

or

```
for my $file (glob '*') {
    print " " x 4, File::Spec->rel2abs($file), "\n";
}
```

I'm using `for` here because it's clearer and more efficient than `map` in void context (you're not collecting a list of results, you just want to output something). On the other hand, if you just want to transform a list, then

```
my @indented = map { " " x 4 . File::Spec->rel2abs($_) } glob '*';
```

would work.

Comment: I'm not sure the efficiency argument still holds, but the fact that `for` expresses the intent more clearly is still sufficient for me.

Comment: @choroba IIRC someone benchmarked it, and `for` was still slightly faster than void `map`.